# Scipy odeint giving index out of bounds errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a differential equation in python using Scipy's odeint function. The equation is of the form `dy/dt = w(t)` where `w(t) = w1*(1+A*sin(w2*t))` for some parameters w1, w2, and A. The code I've written works for some parameters, but for others I get given index out of bound errors.

Here's some example code that works

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate

t = np.arange(1000)

w1 = 2*np.pi
w2 = 0.016*np.pi
A = 1.0

w = w1*(1+A*np.sin(w2*t))

def f(y,t0):
    return w[t0]

y = integrate.odeint(f,0,t)
```

Here's some example code that doesn't work

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate

t = np.arange(1000)

w1 = 0.3*np.pi
w2 = 0.005*np.pi
A = 0.15

w = w1*(1+A*np.sin(w2*t))

def f(y,t0):
    return w[t0]

y = integrate.odeint(f,0,t)
```

The only thing that changes between these is that the three parameters w1, w2, and A are smaller in the second, but the second one always gives me the following error

```
line 13, in f 
   return w[t0]

IndexError: index 1001 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1000
```

This error continues even after restarting python and running the second code first. I've tried with other parameters, some seem to work, but others give me different index out of bounds errors. Some say 1001 is out of bounds, some say 1000, some say 1008, ect.

Changing the initial condition on y (the second input for odeint, which I have as 0 on the above codes) also changes the number on the index error, so it might be that I'm misunderstanding what to put here. I wasn't told what the initial conditions should be other than that y is used as a phase of a signal, so I presumed it to be initially 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is

```
def w(t):
    return w1*(1+A*np.sin(w2*t))

def f(y,t0):
   return w(t0)
```

Array indices are typically integers, time arguments and values of solutions of differential equations are typically real numbers. Thus there is some conceptual difficulty in invoking `w[t0]`.

You might also try to integrate directly the function `w`, there is no inherent difficulty in this example.

---

As for coupled systems, you solve them as coupled systems.

```
def w(t):
    return w1*(1+A*np.sin(w2*t))

def f(y,t):
   wt = w(t)
   return np.array([ wt, wt*sin(y[1]-y[0]) ])
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. The reason I wasn't using normal integration was because after soving `dy/dt = w(t)` I had a second ode to solve: `dz/dt = 1.5*w(t)*sin(z(t)-y(t))` This recreates the same situation I had at first as odeint returns an array which I need to use in the second, but it seems to be working for now.

Comment: You solve a system of ODE as a system of ODE, i.e., using vector-valued functions. see new section